# Detect where the user came from using php

Tags: php

I have this code on members.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
header( 'Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php' ) ; }

else {  
echo "Ok";
}
```

I am trying to avoid people access my members.php without being redirected by my domain
but if a user clicks on a link from facebook for example... he can access the members.php

How can I make the HTTP_REFERER to check if he is being redirected by mywebsite.com ?!

This way I made its working on people who tries to make a direct access by typing the url.
But its not checking the source it came from.

Comment: This is a bad idea, and you're not going to get it working the way you want.

Comment: There is a better way I can prevent people access members.php?!
I thought maybe creating a session, but I do not know how to

Comment: Lots of smart phones and tablets don't send that header! Don't use it!

Comment: @undone Most phones and tablets do send a `Referer` header, but they aren't required to.

Comment: I cant make a way to work ... =(

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use preg_match() to match the whether the user was redirected form facebook or not

```
     <?php
    if(preg_match('#https?\://(?:www\.)?facebook\.com#',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){

    // facebook refered user

    }
    else{

    // else part
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Nice... and to check direct access from browser? There is a way...
this code u made could help me a lot, since 99% are from facebook!

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous reasons and circumstances where `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` has no value.

You can "attempt" to use it, and if you have a value in there use it precariously to do something.

But given the chances of it being empty, or inaccurate, you shouldn't  do something as hardened as a redirect if it's empty.

i.e. You could use it on a 404 not found page to *attempt* to see where the user came from, and from there *attempt* to see where they might have tried to go/come from, and serve them some links on your site which they might find useful.

But simply don't trust it as anything other than a bit of potentially useful info which can very easily be inaccurate and (most likely) empty.

EDIT:
Reading your comment, I see you were trying to use this to prevent access to a members area.
This is a really bad approach, as it tells you nothing of value in terms of managing access to a member area.

I'm not even sure why you thought someone coming from another page from your site should warrant them access to a "members area".
Surely there's no real difference (in terms of "member") from: 1) Coming from external site to your members area, than 2) Coming from external site to *some page* on your site then the members area?

You are going to have to learn to use $_SESSIONS, and if the member area is a secure area, then you will need a register and login system too.
It depends on what you're trying to protect really. That's out of the scope of this question now, however.

If you search Stack for login system and $_SESSION you'll be able to get some info.